# Elasticsearch Node.js client get term suggestions?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

How to get term suggestions from Elasticsearch using Node.js client? I'm trying to find some examples on the elastic [document page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html) to implement search auto-completion like [google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yWxh.png):

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({ node: 'http://192.168.99.100:9200' })

router.get('/elastic/search', async(req, res) => {

    const result = null; // todo

    res.send(result)
})
```

Comment: Question is very wide and vague. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please provide what you have tried till now and where exactly is help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester), the completion suggester provides auto-complete/search-as-you-type functionality.